# Actualizar URL con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo este codigo PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["boton4"]))
{ 
 $finalcode = 'RV-'.createRandomPassword(); 
 header("location: ventas.php?codventa='".$finalcode."'");
}
?>
```

Lo que hace es actualizar el código y cambiarlo en la url, pero nada mas cambia el código y no lo actualiza en la url, por que esta pasando esto??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que se me ocurrió para solucionar este problema fue usar un poquito de javascript y de esa manera si actualizaba la url

```
function ActualizarCodigo(codigo)
{
    window.location.href = 'ventas.php?codventa=' + codigo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este, primero la "L" debe se en mayuscula y segundo la gerarqui de comillas influye...

```
header('Location: ventas.php?codventa='.$finalcode);
```

si te ayudo, marcala como resuelta .) BY srJJ

Comment: No funciona ese codigo

Comment: me falto el punto antes de la variable, ya deberia :)

Comment: Puse el punto porque sabia que faltaba pero ni aun asi funcionó

Comment: tambien es de tener en cuenta que eso es solo para algun archivo que este dentro de la misma gerarquia de las carpetas, es decir si el archivo esta en otra carpeta diferente debes poner la ruta de la carpeta tambien ejemplo "nombre_carpeta/ventas.php" o si esta en una carpeta atras seria "../ventas.php"

Comment: que error te sale ?

Comment: No sale ningun error solo no se actualiza el codigo en la url

Comment: Has comprobado que entras al if? Y hecho un echo de $finalcode?

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate de no tener nada de código html por encima de la etiqueta.
Location es con 'L' y la variable en la URL no va entre comillas.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["boton4"])) { 
     $finalcode = 'RV-'.createRandomPassword(); 
     header("Location: http://www.midominio.com/ventas.php?codventa=".$finalcode);
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

entonces amigo, debes revisar la condicion, pueda ser que no este entrando a la condicion, por eso nunca te lo genera... dentro del if debes poner algo para probrar si entro o no, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["boton4"]))
  { 

   $finalcode = 'RV-'.createRandomPassword(); 
   echo "<script> console.log('$finalcode');</script>";
   //header("location: ventas.php?codventa='".$finalcode."'");
  }
?>
```

en este caso te imprimira en consola el valor de la variabe `$finalcode` (si no sabes sacar la consola del navegador con F12 y en las pestañas dice consola) ahi te daras cuenta si esta entrando al if, detalla que comente el hearde para que no redirecciones, ya que si lo dejas re direccionara y no te permitira ver. me cuentas que sucedio

Comment: es mejor que edites tu respuesta para añadir esta parte en lugar de dar dos respuestas

Comment: ok, bueno señora, se me paso, lo iba a poner en comentario, pero como se paba del limite lo puse aqui y no acate de editar la respuesta...  sorry